# How to add computers to Android USB debug whitelist

Tags: android, debugging

In Android 4.2 a new feature has been introduced: the USB debug whitelist. If I get right, when Android device is connected to ADB for the first time, it remembers the computer it's connected to and then rejects attempts to attach debugger from any other machines.

I have an Android-based smartphone and I need to be able to debug on it from different machines (at home, in the office, etc). So, how do I add additional computers to the whitelist? Some people suggest editing `adb_keys` file on the smartphone, but this requires rooting the device, which I would like avoid for a number of reasons. Are there any other options left?

Comment: You can whitelist more than one computer by default. To add more to the list, just check that "remember this decision" box is ticked when you allow the computer. It adds to the list, not replace the current computer.

Comment: The problem is that right now ADB just does not see the device on any computer (except the one it was paired with for the first time) and no prompt to allow new machines is shown on the device. What am I missing?

Comment: Note that this process tends to silently fail if the screen is locked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that what you have described is the actual behaviour:

When you plug the phone into the PC the fingerprint of the PC is shown and the user is asked if debugging **from this PC** should be allowed.

In my experience plugging the phone into another PC shows a dialogue with a different fingerprint i.e. the question is asked again.

If your device is not seen on a PC i.e. there is no ADB driver under the device list then you have a hardware or driver problem and I would suggest installing the latest drivers for your device. Some devices also require adding the USB VID value to the adb ini file:

[[FIX] USB Vendor ID's - Make your Android devices co-exist in a single machine](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1479311)